# Categorize by columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Have no idea what I'm to name this request so therefore I have not found any answers to it.
Basically a common statement like:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,E FROM TABLE
```

Example result:

```
A B C D E
1 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 7 8 9
2 1 4 5 6
```

How do I 'categorize' by certain columns (in example A and B) so column values are omitted?

Preferred result:

```
A B C D E
1 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
    7 8 9
2 1 4 5 6
```

Comment: So, you want to show only those rows which have a distinct combination of certain columns e.g. distinct values in A and B in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I guess it would make sense to have the result ordered by A,B?
In that case you could use:

```
SELECT DECODE(RN,1,A,NULL) AS A,
  DECODE(RN,1,B,NULL)      AS B,
  C,
  D,
  E
FROM
  (SELECT A,
    B,
    row_number() over (partition BY A,B order by A,B) AS RN,
    C,
    D,
    E
  FROM
    (SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE ORDER BY A,B
    )
  );
```

Comment: In my case this is the most smooth solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAG` [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652) to access previous row values. See below example:

```
SELECT case
         when LAG(a, 1, NULL)
          OVER(ORDER BY a, b, c, d, e) = a and LAG(b, 1, NULL)
          OVER(ORDER BY a, b, c, d, e) = b then
          null
         else
          a
       end new_a,
       case
         when LAG(a, 1, NULL)
          OVER(ORDER BY a, b, c, d, e) = a and LAG(b, 1, NULL)
          OVER(ORDER BY a, b, c, d, e) = b then
          null
         else
          b
       end new_b,
       c,
       d,
       e
  FROM t_table t
 ORDER BY a, b, c, d, e;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f508e/11/0).

Comment: Thank you, this do work. My problem is that I have eight columns of 'A' and 'B'. Only the first LAG iteration would look like:  LAG(IFSAPP.ENG_PART_MASTER_API.GET_PART_DESCRIPTION(A.PART_NO),1,NULL) 
    OVER(ORDER BY IFSAPP.ENG_PART_MASTER_API.GET_PART_DESCRIPTION(A.PART_NO),A.PART_NO,A.PART_REV,A.SUB_PART_NO,A.SUB_PART_REV,POS,QTY,IFSAPP.ENG_PART_MASTER_API.GET_PART_DESCRIPTION(A.SUB_PART_NO))=
    IFSAPP.ENG_PART_MASTER_API.GET_PART_DESCRIPTION(A.PART_NO)

Comment: @Hanseman You can wrap your original query with another one and do case calculations in the outer part. This simplifies and shortens things a bit. But probably you should update the question with your real requirements, so it will be easier to advice for your particular case.

Comment: Thank you, that is right. Still, using row numbers creates the cleanest query. :-)